# Repeat WHILE with the same SELECT

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Why can not I use the same `while` twice?

I would like to repeat the same while on the page and I can not, just load the first one.

Example:

```
$rs = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM site WHERE id = '".$cliente."' ");
$row = $rs->fetch_assoc();
```

While 1 (Located at the top of the site)

```
<?php do{ ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $ID; ?>">
        <?php echo $nome; ?>
    </option>
<?php } while ($row = $rs->fetch_assoc()); ?>
```

While 2 (Located at the end of the site)

```
<?php do{ ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $ID; ?>">
        <?php echo $nome; ?>
    </option>
<?php } while ($row = $rs->fetch_assoc()); ?>
```

Thank you.

Comment: use **parameterised queries** to improve performance, save you from a ton of bugs and **secure** your database. right now, your code is vulnerable to **SQL injection attacks**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store your results in an array instead, and loop that where needed. Otherwise you will need to reset the cursor of your result before looping again.

```
$query = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM site WHERE id = '".$cliente."' ");
$result = $query->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

// Loop wherever needed
foreach ($result as $r) {
    // Use $r
}

// Loop the result again!
foreach ($result as $r) {
    // Use $r
}
```

Also recommend you use a prepared statement instead of using a direct query with variables injected into it.

- [PHP.net on `mysqli_result::fetch_all()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php)

Answer (score 2):

When you do `$rs->fetch_assoc()` you are pulling out rows from result array, to use while with that condition multiple times you have to popolate `$rs` again by executing query again before while or I recomend to save your result to another variable and use it at any time like this

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM site WHERE id = '".$cliente."' ");
$rs = $result;
$row = $rs->fetch_assoc();

//WHILE 1
<?php do{ ?>
<option value="<?php echo $ID; ?>">
      <?php echo $nome; ?>
</option>
<?php } while ($row = $rs->fetch_assoc()); ?>
//$rs is empty now

$rs = $result; //setting $rs again
//WHILE 2
    <?php do{ ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $ID; ?>">
          <?php echo $nome; ?>
    </option>
    <?php } while ($row = $rs->fetch_assoc()); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The first loop consumed all the data in the MySQL.

So, second loop has nothing to consume.

What you can do is:

Get all the data from first loop in one array.

Use it at second time.

Also, you are increasing server trips between PHP and MySQL.

You should always tend to reduce PHP and MySQL server trips.